# My controller.js file breaks when I try to add another controller in it

Tags: angularjs, controller

I was trying to work on my project and build angular controllers to hold data for two different pages.

The code on the first page is...

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="shopItemController">
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="shopItem in shopItems">
<div class="imag"></div>
<h2>{{ shopItems.name }}</h2>
<div class="hf">Buy it: {{ shopItems.price }}</div>
<div class="hff">Earn it: {{ shopItems.altprice }}</div>
<div class="desc"><div>{{ shopItems.desc }}</div></div>
<div class="prog"><div>{{ shopItems.progress }}</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

...and the second page is here.

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="trophyEarnsController">
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="trophyEarn in trophyEarns">
<div class="imag"></div>
<h2> {{ trophyEarns.name }} </h2>
<!--<div class="hf">Buy it: {{ trophyEarns.price }}</div>
<div class="hff">Earn it: {{ trophyEarns.altprice }}</div>-->
<div class="desc"><div> {{ trophyEarns.desc }} </div></div>
<div class="prog"><div> {{ trophyEarns.progress }} </div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
var shopItems = angular.module('shopItems', []);
var trophyEarns = angular.module('trophyEarns', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['shopItems', 'trophyEarns']);

shopItems.controller('shopItemController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shopItems = [{
            //id: 01,
            name: 'One',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 02,
            name: 'Two',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description.',
            prog: '50%'
        }];

});

trophyEarns.controller('trophyEarnsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.trophyEarns = [{
            //id: 01,
            name: 'One',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 02,
            name: 'Two',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description.',
            prog: '50%'
        }];
});
```

This is my first time writing this on my own. It works in my fiddle with one.

http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/rfg80gye/28/

But when I changed it around and tried to add another controller to the controller.js, it broke.

Any help is welcome. This will probably take me at least a week to fix on my own.

Comment: nothing obvious in code shown or structure. What errors get thrown?

Comment: no errors are being thrown. It's just not showing what's in the {{ }}. The ng-repeat is working though.

Comment: you have a typo in view is why ... you named each repeated item so close to array name but used `s` for each item within repeat so is looking at whole array

Comment: Where exactly is the typo. I'm sorry I'm not following?

Comment: `{{ trophyEarns.name }}` should be `{{ trophyEarn.name }}` no plural for the items

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I will try and update this tonight.